# How to avoid overlaps in d3js scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have some random data points[{label, count},....] and simply want to plot them on a 2D Scatter plot. But I am not sure if there is a way to avoid overlapping of any two bubbles.

Lets say I have a plane of 600x600. So all I want to do is just scatter the points anywhere on the chart with only condition that no two bubbles(i.e. data points) should overlap or hide each other on the plane.

Comment: Use a force simulation... but don't forget to tell your readers that the position of the dots **is not exact**, which is a basic premise of any scatterplot. If you paste a working code for the scatter plot I can show you how to do it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Thanks, here is a codepen link I am trying to do this:
http://codepen.io/imdigvijay/pen/xqLNaN

Comment: It doesn't work with random data: we cannot test if the force is really working.

Comment: The data will be coming from a json file. Right now I am just creating random values. If it helps, data list objects may contains integers(count property) 1 to 20K

Comment: So you want to actually **move** the points so they don't overlap?

Comment: @Mark: in a sense yes, that is what my goal is